# How to find next visit in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `visit_record`:

```
customer_id visit_month
000001      1
000001      3
000001      7
000001      8
000002      2
000002      3
      ...
```

I want to output the following:

```
customer_id visit_month next_visit
    000001      1       3
    000001      3       7
    000001      7       8
    000001      8       null
    000002      2       3
    000002      3       5
               ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lead()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select customer_id, 
       visit_month,
       lead(visit_month) over (partition by customer_id order by visit_month) as next_visit
from visit_record
order by customer_id, visit_month;
```